# Reference Chains causing duplicate references/ambiguous calls

Tags: .net, devexpress, project-reference

I have a solution with an MVC UI which references DevExpress libraries.

I have a separate dll that I've referenced as a helper, which was build using DevExpress libraries, thus:

```
MyFramework -> DevEx libs
Build to dll(s)

MyWebUI -> DevEx Libs
MyWebUI -> MyFramework.dll
```

With this setup, when I try to run the UI application I get the following error on view compilation:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.HtmlHelperExtension.DevExpress(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' and 'DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI.HtmlHelperExtension.DevExpress(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)'

If I remove the `MyFramework` reference from the UI project, this doesn't happen.

It seems to be the case that these devexpress libraries are being referenced twice, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.  In the UI project's references list, each of the DevEx libraries are of course only listed once, and there's a single reference to my framework dll.

I don't know if this is a DevEx issue or a general reference issue in .NET (my guess would be the latter).

Answer (score 0):

Every time, no sooner do I post it than I find my answer.

DevExpress has two references that are kind of odd: `DevExpress.Web.Mvc` and `DevExpress.Web.Mvc5`

They're kind of odd in that it's all the same namespaces/object paths etc.

In one project I had the `Mvc5` version referenced, and in the dll I had `Mvc` referenced.  I matched the two and now I'm good.